# C++ statistical package similar to Java's JSci

Tags: java, c++, statistics

I am wondering if there is a package in C++ similar to Java's JSci (http://jsci.sourceforge.net/) where I can, for example, generate parameters of a statistical distribution given an array of empirical data.

I have looked through Boost as a start and didn't see anything that fit what I needed, but perhaps it's there and I just haven't found it yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Boost can also compute statistical distirbutions according to the doc http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/math/doc/html/dist.html

Comment: specifically I am looking to fit to an exponential distribution: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/dist_ref/dists/exp_dist.html

this class doesn't seem to support that, or maybe I missed it?

Comment: @JoeMcG The maximum likelihood estimator for the parameter of an exponential distribution is just 1/(sample mean). Perhaps that's enough.

Comment: @RobertDodier, Duh, can't believe I forgot that. I will do that and see if it works out for what I need and get back on here. thanks!

Comment: That works out fine for my purposes, but other distributions may be of interest. I'll cross those bridges when I come for them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JoeMcG The maximum likelihood estimator for the parameter of an exponential distribution is just 1/(sample mean). Perhaps that's enough. – Robert Dodier 2 days ago

This works fine for my purposes. If anyone knows of something similar to JSci, though, that would still be helpful maybe for others.